# How to serve static files from .NET Core API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, nfs

The API is using .NET Core 3.1 and the folder structure is as follows:

Solution

--Project1

--Project2

Where `Project 2` depends on `Project 1` and is the entry point.

The API is hosted on kubernetes and a NFS share is mounted at `/storage`. The API will need to retrieve and serve files in this file share. So what I did was using the following in my `startup.cs` in `Project2`:

```
app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"storage")),//this will return /app/storage 
    RequestPath = new PathString("/resources")
});
```

I know one of the file is there by checking:

```
  System.IO.File.Exists(@"/app/storage/test.JPG");
```

However, when I tried to access the file by going to `http://myapiurl/resources/test.JPG`, I always got a `404 not found`.

I was wondering what I was missing?

Answer (score 1):

You're using `UseFileServer`, but you're not enabling directory browsing nor serving default files, so I'd recommend narrowing instead to using `UseStaticFiles`.

The easiest way to enable this is to just place the following in your `Startup.cs` file in your `Configure()` method.

```cs
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions 
{
  FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
    Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "storage")),
    RequestPath = "/resources"
});
```

My guess for why this isn't working for you is that `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory`, when running in K8 isn't yielding the same path you see when running locally, so it's not ultimately pointing at /app/storage (which is why your `File.Exists` check works fine because you're not building the path out dynamically).

Use some logging to verify that it's pulling from the right path in your configuration at runtime.

Comment: Thanks! I tried UseStaticFiles but it's still not working. Also Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"storage") does give me '/app/storage' from k8s. If I use env.ContentRootPath, the 'DirectoryNotFoundException' would be logged when I viewed the pod log. I can see that /app/storage does exists when I ran command to list contents in the container and the file is in there too

Comment: If you use UseFileServer and toggle the directory browser argument to true, are you able to recognize any of the files, if any, it might show if you just visit /resources? Again, perhaps it's mapping somewhere unexpected.

Comment: I tried EnableDirectoryBrowsing=true and still got 404 for http://myapiurl/resources. The Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"storage")) returns true.This is really puzzling!

Comment: Just to rule out a silly problem, in your `Configure()` method at the bottom of Startup.cs, are you setting up `app.UseStaticFiles();` followed by `app.UseRouting();` then `app.UseEndpoints();` per the default template setup?

Comment: That's an idea. I was using app.UseMvc() at the end but have removed that and used app.UseStaticFiles followed by  app.UseRouting() and then  app.UseCors, app.UseHeaderPropagation, app.UseAuthentication, app.UseAuthorization and finally   app.UseEndpoints(ep => ep.MapControllers()). Still the same problem.....

Comment: Where did you try the File.Exists check? Have you tried placing that in the constructor for the UseStaticFiles method just to see if it can find the files at that particular part of the operation (e.g. UseStaticFiles(opt => {_logger.LogTrace(File.Exists("path\file.json")); return new PhysicalFileProvider(//...);});

Comment: I did check file exists and directory exists in Startup.cs. An exception would be thrown if the directory can't be found when calling UseStaticFiles.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with static files after switching from AppService to k8s with ingress. It turned out to be problem with case-sensitivity in the URL. Some directories were uppercase, but in paths I had all lowercase letters. It was working locally on Windows and on AppService but not on k8s.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to serve the static files i.e, content and web root

Webroot is used to serve the public and static resource files like css, html, js etc.

You need to enable the static files in startup class and use 'IWebHostEnvironment' to read the static content from wwwroot folder.

You can read the full article [here](https://www.codetolive.in/c%23/.net/Using-static-files-in-ASP-NET-Core/)